# Why wouldn't this longitudinal EM wave propagate in free space?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am learning about EM waves and am getting confused. Here is a picture from an intro. textbook I am using.
[image]

Looking at this, it is clear that both E and B are perpendicular to the direction of motion, and all is fine. However, let's say the wave was propagating at an angle theta to the z axis. In this case, you can still draw the E and B field perpendicular to the direction of motion (with E in the same plane as the direction of motion and B perpendicular to the plane of motion as in the picture), but now there would be a component of the E field that is in the direction of z, even though the E field is still perpendicular. In this case, why wouldn't the EM wave propagate with this longitude component? What am I missing here? Here's a crappy picture of what I mean:
[image]

In the picture you see that the wave is propagating in a direction with a non-zero x and z component and clearly the E field also has nonzero components in the x and z direction, so wouldn't these components be "longitudinal waves" as they are propagating in the direction of motion?

Answer (score 3):

The coordinate independent condition is that the wave-vector (which points in the direction of propagation) and the electric field vector are perpendicular, which we can equivalently say means these vectors have zero dot product

$$
\vec{E} \cdot \vec{k} = 0
$$

Taking your picture, the $k$ vector points in the direction $\hat{k}$

$$
\hat{k} = \cos\theta \hat{z} + \sin \theta \hat{x}
$$
where $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{z}$ are unit vectors pointed along the $x$ and $z$ axes, respectively.

Meanwhile, the $E$ field points in the direction $\hat{E}$

$$
\hat{E} = -\sin \theta \hat{z} + \cos\theta \hat{x}
$$

Computing the dot product, we see explicitly that the condition $\vec{E}\cdot\vec{k}=\hat{E}\cdot\hat{k}=0$ is satisfied
$$
\hat{E} \cdot \hat{k} = -\cos\theta \sin\theta + \sin\theta \cos\theta = 0
$$
Note that we've used $\hat{x}\cdot\hat{x}=\hat{z}\cdot\hat{z}=1$ and $\hat{x}\cdot\hat{z}=0$.

Comment: That makes sense, so in the picture I drew we would not describe any component of the E field as a longitudinal wave propagating, correct?

Comment: Correct. A longitudinal $E$ field would have $\hat{E}\cdot\hat{k} \neq 0$.

Comment: Last follow-up. This is another picture from a different textbook on optics - it is specifically referring to EM waves in a waveguide. (https://gyazo.com/14198882572bc60920c76d69376c74ab). In that picture it describes image b with the following: (https://gyazo.com/807689478172fb228454f218075a58cf). The reason I am confused originally was reading this - it seems like they imply in this similar situation that Ez is now a longitudinal wave that wouldn't be possible in free space?

Comment: @fordanjen Correct. In a waveguide you can have non-zero longitudinal components of the electric field, which you cannot have in free space.